# Как не показывать блок семь дней?

Tags: jquery, html, cookie, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт для того, чтобы данный попап после первого показа не отображался следующую неделю.

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
/* Всплывающее окно */  
#parent_popup {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#popup { 
  background: #fff;
    max-width: 520px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border: 10px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
    /*--CSS3 CSS3 Тени для Блока--*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    /*--CSS3 Закругленные углы--*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#popup h1{
    font:28px Monotype Corsiva, Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #008000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }
#popup h2{
    font:24px Monotype Corsiva, Arial;      
    color: #008000;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }
/* кнопка закрытия */
.close {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    top: -24px;
    width: 24px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 69, 0, 0.8);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent_popup" onclick="document.getElementById('parent_popup').style.display='none';">
  <div id="popup">
```

Здесь содержание:

```
<a class="close" title="Закрыть" onclick="document.getElementById('parent_popup').style.display='none';">X</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var delay_popup = 5000;
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('parent_popup').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно после показа добавлять cookie с временем жизни 7 дней, в случае если установлена попап не отображать.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно записывать счетчик показов куда-либо и по нему проверять.

Вопрос не полный, так как не указано, для кого показывать 2 раза и скрывать: для каждого клиента либо для всех.